# What are good alternatives for 'Admiral' in a space force?

Tags: science-fiction, culture, military, names

I'm currently writing a far-future sci-fi novel. I have officer ranks and their equivalent positions sorted for my space force, I have decided to follow my in-universe naval rank structure for a variety of reasons.

However this all comes with the caveat that I want an alternative to 'Admiral' for my 1*-5* ranks, so as to give the space force its own identity and not have it be just another naval-carbon-copy. So any suggestions would be appreciated. Ideally I would like a name that has a space-y etymological connection or flavour, but any uncommon and sensible suggestions are appreciated!

I wouldn't normally post a general request for ideas online but I have been failing to come up with a rank on my own for months and just wish to resolve this sticky little worldbuilding issue.

EDIT: To be absolutely clear I am trying to **avoid** naval connotations in this rank. Also I should mention that I am looking for a more practical grounded military flavour, over aristocratic themes like 'Lord'. Latin is out of the running as well as I use it a fair bit already in other contexts and don't want to come off as too 40k. As for variations (such as the rear, vice or fleet variants to denote the grades of Admiralty) I already have those sorted, I am just looking for assistances with the core title word.

Thanks in advance!
-Frank

Comment: There are some no-longer-used ranks from historical militaries you might go for (can't think of any that tend naval though), some generic ones ("Marshal"), and even foreign translations of all of the above. If those aren't sufficient to your story, you might pull a Turtledove and go with "Fleetlord" (captains of single vessels were "Shiplords").

Comment: @JohnO Sorry if I worded my question poorly, I am intending to *AVOID* naval connotations with the flag rank that will replace admiral. I am already using Marshal as a cross-branch common rank and the Lord styling does not fit the theme I'm afraid. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: (1) The head of a Roman fleet was not called admiral, for the obvious reason that admiral is an Arabic word, and the Romans did not use Arabic words. How did the Romans call the commanding officer of a fleet? Research! (2) The head of the Eastern Roman / Byzantine fleet was called "megaduke". Isn't that a great title? (3) The Greek language has a beautiful non-Arabic word for "admiral". What is the Greek word for admiral? Research! (4) In the 1930s the Soviet Union went through a phase when they reintroduced military ranks, but avoided the use of the usual words. How did they call an admiral?

Comment: @AlexP If memory serves right, the Romans simply appointed army commanders to naval ships as they did with army soldiers and crews. As for the politicians leading the armies I imagine they stuck with their usual iconic titles such as consul, when commanding at sea, but I'll have to look into it. As for the Greek - I don't know if we are thinking of the same word but I think you refer to one I already knew, that being Navarchos. I had already discarded this word as it has obvious naval connotations which I am trying to avoid in this rank. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: The Romans called the commander of a fleet Prefect. The Soviets called and admiral a Flagman. (For real, Флагман.)

Comment: @JohnO, having been on a Halo kick lately, I am reminded of Shipmaster, and the presumably-corresponding Fleetmaster. Might throw Groupmaster into that mix, also, for formations smaller than a fleet.

Comment: @Matthew That's not bad actually... works in non-naval contexts too. Jetmaster, tankmaster, etc.

Comment: @AlexP The Romans called a lot of roles prefect xD Ancient Latin was a funny language. I can see why they have a naval rank called Flagman but again that has heavy naval connotations.

Comment: @AlexP I honestly don't understand why you would choose to leave an incomplete answer as a comment and tell OP to research the rest themselves. Particularly for such obscure historical details as the 1930s Soviet Navy naming conventions. Are you implying that such things are common knowledge?

Comment: VTC as the 'best answer' is entirely opinion based.

Comment: @JohnO, similarly, jetlord, tanklord... [oh, wait](https://www.baen.com/the-tank-lords.html) . More generally, <thing>{lord,master,commander,captain,etc.}.

Comment: @FrankRebin, I'm not sure about "flagman" being naval. A "flag" is an indicator of rank / command, although I suppose on land, "standard" or "banner" might be more typical. (Despite that the *physical* objects are essentially the same.)

Comment: @Trioxidane If we were strict about closing every Worldbuilding question that's opinion based, we'd have three or four workable questions a day.

Comment: @ZeissIkon entirely true. That is why I, not the community of stack exchange, decided to VTC this one. I personally decided this was too opinion based for me. Others can join in this vote if they decide the same. I personally don't think I'm too strict on this one with this vote. Good that this is a comment where we don't do this, or I would VTC this reaction.

Comment: @KeizerHarm: Lo and behold, the Fount of All Knowledge has an article on the [history of Russian military ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Russian_military_ranks). The thought process was -- we want unusual words for military ranks -- remeber that the Soviets went through a phase when they used bizarre made-up words for military ranks -- look for that phase in Wikipedia. (And it's not an answer because the question cannot be answered. I even downvoted it. But, after downvoting I felt remorseful and wanted to provide some help.)

Comment: While I think that the question asks for opinions, I still think it should not be closed as it somewhat meets the [requirements for allowed subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). It might be more fitting for Writing.SE, though.

Comment: @AlexP Please be aware that you did not provide any help after needlessly downvoting my query. From your comments it seems like you misread or misunderstand the question entirely in fact, for instance the idea that I wanted unusual words for military ranks. I didn't want to say anything outright but seeing as you wish to be condescending without adding to the discussion I would like this to be known. I don't intend you any offence only constructive criticism.

Comment: @Matthew Hi Matthew you're probably right! I just have a particular interest in the Age of Sail and things like the rank of flag captain probably cause a bias resulting in my naval association of the word. :P

Comment: you can look at the ancient Roman rank system as "legat","praetor", etc; greek "navarch", "stratig".. any caste system at all...  ; Or,I remember an interesting system of Michailov, "Then come and judge" - like "shtab-cornet", "flag-cornet", "bayonet-capral", etc :)
http://www1.lib.ru/RUFANT/MIHAJLOW_W/uldemir2.txt 

...Words like "Coordinator" ...
or to use certain circumstances of your world - religion, exotic specific objects, sea/space therms as a parts, animals - "Great Combat SpermWhale", GCSW, why not? - tell us more about him

Comment: Matthew, the flagman is a specific naval therm - it happened historically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Controller**

I suggest "Controller" as a throwback to the (current) days when "Ground Control" were the ones giving orders.  Sure the astronauts/cosmonauts in the capsule/station have a commander, and he's in charge for split-second decisions.  But in general both the day-to-day general tasks, the overall mission, and Big Problem Situation orders get relayed from/decided on by ground control.  That's obviously changed, but perhaps "ground control" becomes slang for "the one calling the shots who isn't on the ship."  Eventually "Ground" drops out of use, as that person may well be on the earth or a space station or even another ship.  Eventually through cultural osmosis "Controller" becomes the word for anyone in charge of a group of starships.
This is very similar to how lots of other military rank titles arose in the past.

Sidenote: The actual title of the person (in the US) in charge of Ground Control is "Director" but as that's in current-use as a common civilian manager title I think it has less chance of becoming the space-navy "admiral" equivalent.

Comment: You know if you register your Email, you can start to participate more fully Dario, you've made valuable contributions, it's a shame to lose the credit for that.

Comment: Bing bing bing! This is exactly what I was looking for! Beautifully well thought out etymological and historical roots whilst still being a normal word readers would understand. You have given me the perfect lightbulb moment. I am going to use this brilliant concept but maybe go with Conductor as it has a grander more far future feel that fits my setting more. Like a great battle is the genius commander's orchestral performance. While still retaining the great connections you made in Controller. Thank you for your brilliant answer. :)

Comment: @FrankRebin Be aware that there is a derogatory term "Space Opera" which is used to refer to simplistic or overly melodramatic Sci-Fi.  If you go with "conductor", there is the very real implication that you are calling your setting a Space Opera.  So, unless you are intentionally creating a tongue and cheek setting, Controller is a much better title to go with... or you could do the real world answer and go with it a General, but I can certainty see the appeal of Controller if you are looking for something more otherly.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Thank you for your concern :) I am aware of space opera and I'm not to worried about that, as my setting on the whole is very grounded and does not tug on suspension of disbelief too heavily I believe I can get away with the odd flare :P.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest variations of "Marshal" -- Grand Marshal of the Space Force (equivalent to Fleet Admiral of the Navy), Grand Marshal, Marshal, Lieutenant Marshal, and Vice Marshal, or variations thereof, should avoid any naval connotation.  These are similar to the ranks used in some ground armies, going at least as far back as Napoleonic times.

Comment: This is the best suggestion yet :). However as I said to someone else the only thing that's always stopped me using Marshal is the fact it is already in use as a cross-branch rank (Field Marshal, Sea Marshal, Air Marshal, Void Marshal) in my setting. But I am honestly *this* close to going with it haha.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a Writing SE question, although I admit there is a valid worldbuilding aspect to it.

Do you want to completely eliminate all connections with fleets and ships, or you just don't want any titles normally associated with it? Also, is your world directly or indirectly associated with any of the known human culture?

One common approach to worldbuilding is to base your society on one (or more) existing cultures. If this is what you are doing, then it would be natural to use words that were used in those cultures, for example [Navarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navarch) or [Procurator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procurator_(ancient_Rome)).

If you want to invent your ranking structure from scratch, it still needs to have connections to modern English. As others had suggested, "General" or "Marshal" titles are the first ones to come to mind, and those titles are perfectly fine if your want to model your space fleet after Army rather than Navy.

When you invent something completely new, you lose connection with modern English, there will be a lot for you to explain, and a lot for the audience to guess. You may come up with something like "[Moff](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Moff)" or "[Grand Moff](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Moff)", but need to understand that this would require more worldbuilding on your part.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am trying to disconnect completely from the navy theme in this rank, as the other officer ranks have some navy connection like midship as the vessels of the force are called voidships. I should said in my Q but yes this is a future human nation. Terms like general marshal and chief are already taken by the other branches. I'm going for some kind of english or other modern language word that sounds good and has I can worldbuild an origin for the term after. One idea i had was meishu which is Japanese for leader but this is only a seed of an idea right now.

Answer (score 2):

### The USA has an actual Millitary Branch called the Space Force with official ranks

This ranking system is more or less taken from the air force rather than the navy; so, the highest ranking officer in the actual real world Space Force is a "General".

**Specifically:**

- 1-star: Brigadier General
- 2-star: Major General
- 3-star: Lieutenant General
- 4-star: General

There is currently no official position for a 5-star General in this branch, but if thier was, it would logically be called "General of the Space Force".

https://www.military.com/space-force/officer-ranks.html

https://www.military.com/space-force/enlisted-ranks.html

French Space Command and Russian Space Forces also seem to have taken to using thier own languages equivalent to General in thier naming conventions (Général and генера́л respectively)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranks_in_the_French_Air_and_Space_Force

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Space_Forces

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am aware of the US space force and, personal opinion alert, I believe it has very little relevance to far future sci-fi writing/worldbuilding. Also it is evident that the use of the term general is likely in part because the whole concept of a space force is in its absolute adolescence and nothing like futuristic warships yet (nor will it likely ever be) and so, similarly to the airforces of WWI, they are starting out with borrowed terms from older branches (in this case the army) which will inevitably be replaced in the near future let alone 1000s of yrs from now.

Answer (score 0):

General, Fleet commander, High commander, Supreme command, warmaster, warleader, Battle leader, Grand battleleader, high prince. A lot depends on the structure of your military and the state for which it fights.

In light of the new edits
I recommend something like warmaster or supreme commander  or high command.  Some less flash more  Utilitarian sounding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Please see my edit, I *just* made it as you answered, for more specific thematic guidelines. I already use commander in a couple ranks and I try to avoid overusing words like that anyway as commander is also a general military term  of course!

Comment: Fleet master. Task group captain. Grand admiral (okay, probably insufficiently different). Star Lord. Duke (if you have conflated military and political ranks). If you aren't talking about humans, First Fang, First Claw, Hive Leader, and so forth become options.

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest titles like flotilla leader, squadron leader, subfleet leader, fleet leader, grand fleet leader, superfleet leader, and so on as admiral equivalents.

Or possibly substitute "commander" for "leader" in those titles and ranks.

Those titles are based on the assumption that "admiral" equivalents will command various sized groups of ships operating together in war games or actual space battles.

Of course in real life admirals are also given command of geographic regions of the ocean, and ships are transferred into and out of their command areas, and so the nuumber of ships they have command of varies over time witout changing the rank of hte admiral in charge of that region.

So possibly you might want to base your ranks on the different levels or areas where the officers command.

If it is a space opera set in interstellar space, "admiral" ranks might be based on the number of star systems where the officer commands the forces.

So the commander of spaces force assets in a singler star system might be a star commander, and the commander in ten systems might be a ten star commander, and the commander in 100 systems might be a hundred star commander, and so on.

Or the commander of forces in one star system might be a first level star commander, the commander of forces in 10 systems might be a second level star commander, the commander of forces in 100 systems might be a third level star commander, and so on.

Or maybe the commanders are given command of forces in cubical regions of space with specified dimensions and volumes, without counting the varying number of stars within them. Each cube of space would be surrounded by other cubes in a three dimensional grid.

In science fiction various regions of interstellar space are often called sectors or quadrants.

If your space realm is large enough, it could have great, ordinary, and small versions of both quadrants and sectors, and thus a total of six levels in the hierarchy of command volumes.  And so "admiral" ranks could be given as sector commander, small quadrant commander, great quadrant commander, etc, arranged in the order that you put the hierarchy of command volumes.

I note that your imaginary space force could have different hierarchies of "admiral" ranks.  In the late Roman Empire a *dux* was the commander of frontier defense forces permanently stationed within the region he commanded, while a *comes* was commander in or of a mobile field force stationed at a central location and sent to the sites of serious conflicts like civil wars, Persian wars, or barbarian invasions.

So a sector leader could command the fores within a star sector, a second level sector leader could command the forces within several sectors, a third level sector leader could lead the forces within several groups of sectors commandered by second level star leaders, and so on.   And a first level star commander could command a group of maybe ten space battleships, a second level star commander command a group of 100 ships, a third level star commander command a group of 1,000 shps, and so on.

Or maybe a defense commander one commands defense forces in one sector, a defense commander two commands defense forces in a group of sectors, etc., while a strike commander one commands ten ships and a strike commander two commands 100 space warships, and so on.

If your space realm rules a significant proportion of the Mikly Way Galaxy, it will have a very complex civil governmeent and military command structure.

There are about one hundrd billion to four hundred billion stars in the Mikly Way Galaxy.

So if there is a decimal command structure, an officer or official with authority in one star system would have a 2nd level boss with authority in 10 systems, who would have a 3rd level boss with authority in 100 systems, who would have a 4th level boss with authority in 1,000 systems, who would have a 5th level boss with authority in 10,000 systems, who would have a 6th level boss with authority in 100,000 systems, who would have a 7th level boss with authority in 1,000,000 systems, who would have a 8th level boss with authority in 10,000,000 systems, who would have a 9th level boss with authority in 100,000,000 systems, etc.

Ruling 100,000,000 star systems would be ruling only one percent or less of the Milky Way Galaxy, and such a realm would look rather small on a map of the entire Milky Way Galaxy.

So if a space realm rules only a few thousand star systems, and has only thousands of space battleships in its fleet, it can get by with only a few ranks equivalent to admiral, like modern navies on Earth do.  But if a space realm is much larger than that - and a space realm that is much larger than that could still be very tiny on a galactic scale - the space navy would have millions of space warships, and there would probably be more admiral ranks than lower officer ranks.

So it is possible that an outstanding space navy officer might start as the equivalent of an ensign and get promoted once every 4 years until becoming the lowest grade admiral equivalent after 24 years, and continue to get a promotion every 4 years in the admiral equivalent ranks, and get promoted to a 9th level admiral equivalent after 36 more years and 60 years in the service.

And yet his realm might be so tiny compared to the whole galaxy that its main strategic worry would be that some as yet undiscovered realm tens of times as powerfull might invade and conquer it with overwealming force.

It is often said that aviation went from the Wright Brothers at Kitty Hawk to the first moon landing in only 66 years.  But space travel is not a branch of aviation.

Space travel went from the first liquid fuel rocket launched by Dr. Robert Goddard - with space travel the ultimate goal of his research - in 1926 to the first moon landing in 1969 in only 43 years.

So I hope that you will not make your space armed force too much like a space air force, since aviation is just as different from space flight as sea travel is.

Answer (score 0):

**A Few Ideas:**

- Space Lord: From the British Sea Lords. However, they operate from central hubs withing the fleet. Goes backwards in rank [ie. rank 3 is higher than rank 1.] Above all is the Lord of His/Her Majesty's Suns, the entire fleet commander [rank 5]. The rest are Space Lords [2-5]. Their rank is told by saying referencing fleets or fleet number. Example, Space Lord Joshua Andrews of the 8th and 9th fleets [rank 2] or Space Lord Kate Rose of 4 fleets [rank 4]. Would work well with any galactic empires.
- War Chief Luzmila: For when the migration of tribes into the stars. Either sedentary, on a planet, or nomadic, residing in a generation ship. They are family. A family of families. There are large families that mainly work family trades, but some become warriors who act as elites and officers during a call to arms, where the warbands move to battle stations. Warriors [5], War Chieftain [4], War Chief [3] War Leader (an elder)[2] The Patriarch or matriarch [1].
- Praetor, Governor, or Consul: The method of the roman senate, and all who wish to emulate. Perfect for fascists, Caesar's Legion, or the result of a time traveler saving Cicero and bringing him to the future.
- Feudal: The lords of vast wealth and space. They are trained from childhood, serve in the military, and, upon their ascension, lead their personal forces. The highest noble is the Fleet Commander or is given charge by the king's orders. Generally a Duke, but really any noble. Rank varies.
- High Military Commissar/High Commander: The Galactic Communist Union and the Union Chairman employ Commissars at the highest level to prevent capitalist subversives. From High Commander to Ship Commander, the Commissariat watches all.
- Commanding Executive Officer (CXO): They say war is unprofitable, I say they are sore losers. Supported by my 1nd Executive Officer down to my 5th Executive Officer (XO ranks 1-5) in the military and the members of the Chief Executive Board with various Chief Executives. And the Board and shareholders to report back to.
- The Marshall: Boats have nothing to do with space, the army created the air force. Now, we will command the Space Force. (just trade navy with army)
- Starategos: Think of independent greek city states but there planets. Freemen will only fight under renown figures such as Nikos Angelis III, the III is his senior officer rank, but all officers fight under their a Starategos from the military council. Governments: Monarchy, Oligarchy , Tyranny, Democracy.
- The Pharaoh: Overseer of the Military (1), Star Commander (2), Overseer of the Frontier Stations(3), Overseer of the Garrison Stations (4), Garrison Commander. Sometimes the Pharaoh and his guard fleet would lead their fleets. A system of Planetary Vizers and Nobles with offices managed the central state with scribes, and the priests practiced religion and provided social services. Last are soldier. The rest are commoners.

I